What conditions on the rate matrix $Q$ ensure unique convergence in continuous-time Markov chains?
In the study of discrete-time Markov chains, the conditions under which all initial distributions converge to a unique stationary distribution are well-understood. Specifically, if the transition matrix $\mathbf{P}$ has all strictly positive entries, this is a sufficient condition. The discrete-time probability transition equation is given by:
$$ \pi(n+1) = \pi(n)\mathbf{P}, $$
where $\pi(n)$ represents the state distribution at time $n$ and $\mathbf{P}$ is the transition matrix. This condition directly relates to the matrix elements and is easy to verify.
For continuous-time Markov chains with finite states, the probabilities follow the Kolmogorov forward equation:
$$ \frac{d\pi(t)}{dt} = \pi(t)\mathbf{Q},$$
where $\pi(t)$ is the probability distribution vector at time $t$ and $\mathbf{Q}$ is the transition rate matrix. I am also interested in understanding the conditions under which this equation converges to a unique stationary distribution.
There seem to be some abstract sufficient and necessary conditions, such as connectivity and irreducibility (as I gathered from ChatGPT, and I'm open to correction if my understanding is wrong). However, these criteria seem somewhat challenging to verify directly.
Question:
I would like to know if there exist any criteria directly related to the elements of the transition rate matrix $\mathbf{Q}$ that can determine whether the continuous-time finite-state Markov chain will converge to a unique stationary distribution. This criterion can be sufficient but not necessary, similar to the discrete-time case where all elements of the transition matrix being strictly positive is a sufficient condition.
Additionally, I am looking for references or textbooks that discuss this specific question.
There is a related question (Convergence to unique stationary distribution for SDEs and Markov processes) I previously asked on MO.
Update:
This question has been answered in MO (What conditions on the rate matrix Q
ensure unique convergence in continuous-time Markov chains?).
